Get all bookmark folders in a Firefox extension
What's the fastest way to retrieve all the folders?
This is what I'm trying, but seems to be very slow:
App.get_bookmark_folders = async (title = ``) => {
  let folders = []
  let nodes = await browser.bookmarks.getTree()
  let max = App.get_setting(`max_bookmark_folders`)
  title = title.toLowerCase()
  let max_depth = 3

  function traverse(bookmarks, depth) {
    if (depth > max_depth) {
      return
    }

    for (let bookmark of bookmarks) {
      if (bookmark.children) {
        if (bookmark.title) {
          if (bookmark.title.toLowerCase().includes(title)) {
            folders.push(bookmark)
          }
        }

        if (folders.length >= max) {
          return
        }

        traverse(bookmark.children, depth + 1)
      }
    }
  }

  traverse(nodes, 1)
  return folders
}

Even if I use max to limit the results to a certain number, it seems to process the whole thing.
What's the fastest way?

As you can see in devtools performance profiler, getTree reads the entire tree, which is the slow part. Your traverse doesn't take any noticeable time at all. There's no API to do what you want.

@woxxom I see ... I wonder if you have any idea of what this extension might be doing https://github.com/aaFn/Bookmark-search-plus-2

https://i.imgur.com/D6vnhG8.png

Supposed to be very fast with many bookmarks. I don't know what api they might be using

I guess it caches the bookmarks in the background script.
